# Where does Xcode save Swift UI preview files?

Tags: xcode, swiftui

When using the live preview feature inside of Xcode for Swift Ui my anti virus scanner (company requirement) is going crazy. I'm assuming that Xcode writes files for the Swift Ui preview to the file system and that is what the virus scanner is detecting and checking.
So I would like to configure the anti virus scanner to exclude the folders where these files will be stored.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the path:

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/Previews
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but I don't see a `Preview` folder under the given path even when starting the preview in Xcode.

Comment: You sure? It shows up when I search for it

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure. Even did a build if maybe that is what you meant. But still no preview folder. I'm running Xcode 13.3.1 and looking in `/Users/USERNAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData`.

Comment: Could the AntiVirus be deleting the folder?

Comment: Maybe, but I don't think so. The preview is working fine, it's just, that the AntiVirus is scanning a lot while the preview is running. Maybe I have to search for a different reason.